# Can i use parse.com for running periodic tasks?

Tags: parse-platform

Can i use parse.com for running periodic cloud code tasks? I've read through documentation, but I've been left under impression, that the only way to run cloud code is to run it as a callback when querying parse server from my frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register it as a background job https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#jobs

Then you can schedule it to run from the dashboard or call it programmatically by some other means.

Comment: thanks, that's true. Well, we've decided that we need a normal backend for out application, so we don't use parse though :)